# How can I return an event duration divided over multiple days in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database that contains Event data. These Events represent a warning state in a system. They have a StartTime, EndTime, Duration (in seconds) and VarName (and some other attributes that are less relevant for the question).

I am trying to write a query that will allow me to represent the amount of time that a certain warning was active *per day*. This way, service engineers can easily see if certain changes/fixes caused a warning to decrease or disappear over time.

A quick-and-dirty first attempt is shown below.

```
SELECT
    [VarName] AS metric,
    SUM([Duration]) AS value,
    Convert(date, [StartTime]) AS date
FROM [dbo].[Events]
WHERE VarName LIKE 'WARN%'
GROUP BY Convert(date, [StartTime]), VarName
ORDER BY date
```

This works well enough when Events last only a short time and handles multiple Events of the same type in a day. But it breaks down when Events span multiple days (or even weeks).

Example:

| VarName | StartTime | EndTime | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WARN_1 | 2021-06-28 23:00:00.000 | 2021-06-29 02:00:00.00 | 10800 |

What I get:

| metric | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WARN_1 | 2021-06-28 | 10800 |

What I want:

| metric | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WARN_1 | 2021-06-28 | 3600 |
| WARN_1 | 2021-06-29 | 7200 |

Taking into account that:

- An event can occur multiple times in the same day
- An event can span multiple days

I'll be fiddling with this today and if I come up with a working solution I'll append it to this post. But I don't work with SQL all that often, and it feels like this may require some more advanced trickery. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If an event has 2 hours in day 1, and 4 hours in day 2 - do you want half value per day, or 1/3 day 1?

Comment: I would want the accurate representation of the amount of hours (in seconds) for each day. In your scenario that would be 7200 seconds in day one, and 14400 seconds in day two. Will update the post to make this more clear.

Comment: You'll start with a subquery that shows your events table in a form where every event that spans multiple days is represented by multiple events that do not span multiple days. Then you'll summarize it as your example shows.

Comment: Correct! Just trying to figure out the proper syntax :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to break the periods into days:

```
with cte as (
      select varname, starttime,
             (case when datediff(day, starttime, endtime) = 0
                   then endtime
                   else dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, starttime))
              end) as day_endtime,
             endtime
      from t
      union all
      select varname, day_endtime,
             (case when datediff(day, starttime, endtime) = 1
                   then endtime
                   else dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, day_endtime))
              end) as day_endtime,
             endtime
      from cte
      where datediff(day, starttime, endtime) > 0
     )
select *
from cte;
```

To aggregate, change the last part to:

```
select varname, convert(date, starttime),
       sum(datediff(second, starttime, day_endtime))
from cte
group by varname, convert(date, starttime);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68208196/how-can-i-return-an-event-duration-divided-over-multiple-days-in-sql/68208348#68208348) is a db<>fiddle.

If you need timespans longer than 100 days, add `option (maxrecursion 0)` or any number larger than about 732.

Comment: Will this work if the date range is within **2021-06-20** to **2021-06-30**?

Comment: At first glance this seems to do the trick perfectly! Running a few more tests right now.

Comment: Don't forget to put `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 732)` after the whole query, or your date-reporting range will be limited to the default of 100 days, (732 gives you two years).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a numbers table, you can join to that based on the difference in days which will give you `n` number of rows for each event based on the days. You then just need to calculate how much of each event falls in that day, which I've done with a case expression:

```
SELECT  t.VarName,
        StartDate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.StartTime)),
        Duration = CASE -- starts and ends on same date
                        WHEN CONVERT(DATE, t.StartTime) = CONVERT(DATE, t.EndTime) THEN t.Duration 
                        -- First Day
                        WHEN n.Number = 0 THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, t.StartTime, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1, t.StartTime)))
                        --Last Day
                        WHEN CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.StartTime)) = CONVERT(DATE, t.EndTime) 
                            THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.StartTime)), t.EndTime)
                        -- Middle Day
                        ELSE 86400
                    END
FROM    @t AS t
        INNER JOIN Numbers AS n
            ON n.Number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, t.StartTime, t.EndTime);
```

If you don't have a numbers table, you can very easily create this on the fly:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (VarName VARCHAR(10), StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME, Duration AS DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime, EndTime));
INSERT @T (VarName, StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES 
    ('WARN_1', '20210628 23:00:00.000', '20210629 02:00:00.00'),
    ('WARN_2', '20210629 11:00:00.000', '20210629 14:00:00.00'),
    ('WARN_3', '20210630 23:00:00.000', '20210704 02:00:00.00');

-- This will do numbers 0-99, add more cross joins if necessary
WITH Numbers (Number) AS
(   SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n1 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n2 (N)
)
SELECT  t.VarName,
        StartDate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.StartTime)),
        Duration = CASE -- starts and ends on same date
                        WHEN CONVERT(DATE, t.StartTime) = CONVERT(DATE, t.EndTime) THEN t.Duration 
                        -- First Day
                        WHEN n.Number = 0 THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, t.StartTime, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1, t.StartTime)))
                        --Last Day
                        WHEN CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.StartTime)) = CONVERT(DATE, t.EndTime) 
                            THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.StartTime)), t.EndTime)
                        -- Middle Day
                        ELSE 86400
                    END
FROM    @t AS t
        INNER JOIN Numbers AS n
            ON n.Number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, t.StartTime, t.EndTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm going with Gordon's solution, as it is seems slightly more simple (and I just finished testing it and it works like a charm :). Very much appreciate you taking the time for the extensive answer & explanation.

Comment: No worries. Be aware that [Recursive CTEs do not scale well](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2). If you have a small data set performance is not likely to be an issue so this won't be relevant to you, but on larger data sets it will be. So may be worth considering

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. We are indeed talking about a fairly small database. Query should yield a few thousand results in extreme cases, but in the regular use-case no more than a few hundred. Default time-range is 30 days or less. Should we run into performance issues I'll know where to look though :) Thanks!